# Amazon Lex - Delete Slot Type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I've added a Slot Type into the web front end system of Lex by clicking on the "Save slot type" button.

But now I can't see the Slot Type anywhere. Nor can I edit it. It just seems to have vanished into thin air. However, when I then try and create another Slot Type with the same name, I receive an error saying that it already exists... which it obviously does, but I can't edit it or delete it because I can't see it.

How do I access it?? or how do I access the json for it???

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just found the answer. Go back to the Lex start page (ie click on the golden box, then locate the Lex feature).

Then on the left is a list of Intents and Slot Types.

Answer (score 0):

This was a cashing issue for me. I closed all browser windows, deleted my cache for the past hour, and logged back into AWS.

Problem solved.

When I did logged back in, the slot was back in my Slot Types, even though I had deleted it (at least it was not showing in my list of Slot Types before). I was able to use it in my bot without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Amazon Console
2. Type Amazon lex
3. On left side there are vertical menu like Bots, Intents, Slot types
4. Click on Slot types . Wait for 2 -3 seconds. Your created slot will appear in the list.